# Checking correctness of finite state automata designed

Tags: automata

How to check correctness of finite state automata we have designed for a regular expression with the help of any computer program or prolog?

Comment: You can check it manually only if it is a small automaton. Try to find a string accepted by automaton but should not be word of the language.

Comment: There is an algorithm for converting regular expressions to finite state automata. Isn't this enough?

Comment: Ayman, could you please tell me more about that algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following steps. Each step is meant to be realized by an algorithm, not manually:

1. Convert the regular expression to a NFA.
2. Convert the NFA to an equivalent DFA.
3. If the FSA that you have defined is a NFA, convert it to an equivalent DFA.
4. Test the two DFAs for equivalence.

Edit: There is an online implementation of the first two steps [here](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa).

For step 4 you can look at slides 2-7 [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2012/course/TMV026/lec10.pdf).

Comment: could you please tell what's NFA?

Comment: A [Non-deterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton).